# Create a CDN proxy in Google Cloud for Segment analytics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cloud-cdn, segment-analytics

I want to create a cdn proxy to send analytic events through a custom domain as detailed here: https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/website/javascript/custom-proxy/

However, in their tutorial they use Amazon CloudFront. What would the equivalent Google Cloud service be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try with [Google Cloud CDN with external origin](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-external-origin).